# Hex - how many in the series 000 through to FFF?

Tags: hex

I am trying to find out how many combinations are possible for 000 through to FFF under hex format? thanks

Comment: 0xFFF + 1 = 4096 combinations ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are 16 choices for each of the 3 digits, so:

```
16*16*16 = 4096
```